# Merging several rows based on conditions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a large database containing  informatiom about orders. Each order has a unique number, a tripnumber it is assigned to and a location number.

It sometimes happens that multiple orders are delivered to the same location, during the same trip. I want to merge these entries into one, as they are skewing my analysis results.

I want to iterate over the entire table, checking in every trip whether there are orders that have the same location number. If so, I want to update the rows in MySQL to either add together the values in the columns of that row or take the maximum of the two.

Is this possible in just MySQL?

I am fairly new to using MySQL (and coding in general) so I'm not sure how to write anything that iterates in it.

Comment: You do not have to update your database, you can take care of this when you do your analysis.

Comment: What do you mean? This skews it as it shows more orders being delivered on time then there actually are. How would you deal with this during analysis?

Comment: By grouping the orders to the same location to the same time together. Keyword here is the group.